# NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject() unarchives old object

Tags: swift, swift3, nsfilemanager, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I want to save the user's filter selections on `FilterViewController`.

When `FilterViewController` is closed, `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject` archives the user's selections. However, `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject` opens up the initial default selections (NOT the user's selections). **How to fix this?**

**FiltersViewController.swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       if let filterSections = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filterViewModel.filtersFilePath) as? [FilterSection] {
            // Retrieves initial default selections, NOT user's selection
            filterViewModel.filterSections = filterSections 
            filtersTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Saves what user selects
    let isSuccessful = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.filterViewModel.filterSections, toFile: self.filterViewModel.filtersFilePath) 
    if (isSuccessful) {
        print("Saved filters") // This is printed
    } else  {
        print("Didn't Save filters")
    }
}
```

**FilterViewModel.swift**

```
class FilterViewModel: NSObject {
    // Contains all filtered sections displayed on table view
    var filterSections: [FilterSection] = []
    // File Path to saved Filter Sections
    var filtersFilePath: String {
        let manager = FileManager.default
        let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        print("this is the url path in the documentDirectory \(url)")
        return (url!.appendingPathComponent("FilterSelectionData").path)
    }

    override init() {
         super.init()
         filterSections = self.getFilterSections()
    }

}
```

**CompanyViewController.swift**

```
@objc func filterButtonTapped() {
        var filterViewModel: FilterViewModel
        if (self.filterViewModel != nil) {
            filterViewModel = self.filterViewModel! // This runs
        }
        else {
            self.filterViewModel = FilterViewModel()
            filterViewModel = self.filterViewModel!
        }
        let filtersVC = FiltersViewController(filterViewModel: filterViewModel)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filtersVC, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: Are you also  archiving default values somewhere?

Comment: Did you implement `NSCoding` in `FilterViewModel`? http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: @Puneet Sharma No default values are created when the view model is first initialized

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I didn't think I needed to? B/c I'm archiving the filterViewModel's sections (`filterViewModel.filterSections`)

Comment: @Alex oh yeah, my mistake.. so I guess you do it in `FilterSection`.. sorry..

Comment: @Alex: This means you are somehow archiving the default values. I would create a debug point in viewWillDisAppear method to check what is getting archived.

Comment: @PuneetSharma I did. I saw that it saves the users selection, but when I re-open up the filter view controller, in `viewWillAppear`, the `filterSelection` is the original default selections

Comment: @Alex: You are using self.getFilterSections to set filterSections in FilterViewModel init. I suppose   self.getFilterSections is a method that returns the default values. For me, it should not be the case and if the you have archived some values, you should get that in this method. Although, this should not be the reason for the issue, but may be a reason for inducing bug. Try changing self.getFilterSections to return archived values if possible otherwise default values and check whether the bug is still there.

Comment: @PuneetSharma that solved it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `self.getFilterSections` to set `filterSections` in `FilterViewModel init`. I suppose `self.getFilterSections` is a method that returns the default values. For me, it should not be the case, rather if you have archived some values, you should get that in this method.
 Although, this alone should not be the reason for the issue, but may be a reason for inducing bug. Try changing `self.getFilterSections` to return archived values if possible otherwise default values and check whether the bug is still there.